# Magento 2 Add input fields to Product Admin

Tags: product, magento-2.1, adminform

I have added various input fields to a tab in the edit product page in the admin area, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="my_field"/>
```

I have an observer and I can get the post fields.

```
$post = $this->_request->getPostValue();
```

I can see all the regular magento fields, but I cannot see the fields I added myself.
How do get my custom fields to post data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have figured this one out.
I added this to the input fields:

```
data-form-part="product_form"
```

Now I can find my data in the post variables!